# unable to locate element method LinkText in c# selenium and visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, selenium

I exported some code from Selenium IDE into my C# page in Visual studio 2013 and it keeps giving me this error. I just copied the steps from the exported document into my c# page. The platform finds the LinkText on the actual page but it keeps giving me this error. 
I changed it to find the element by id but, then I don't know how to select the menu item in webpage. 
I will really appreciate your help with this.
Thank you

I get this error:

> {"Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"link text\",\"selector\":\"My Resume\"}"}**

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace MyFirstAutoScript
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://yelitzascareerjourney.wordpress.com/");
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Resume")).Click(); //my page brakes here
            more commands go here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add wait function to appear element

Comment: this happens when a link does not exist on the page with the text `"My Resume"`.  first thing i should ask - are you sure it is a link, and not a button?  It's common to get confused `<a class="button">My Resume</a>` and `<button>My Resume</button>`.  `By.LinkText` only finds `<a>`'s

Comment: Try driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("My Resume")).Click();

Comment: Have you tried my answer, please let me know that worked or not?

Answer (score 2):

> You must have to mouseover first on menu item "About Me" before
>   clicking on sub menu item "My Resume". And you can use Actions commands from Selenium for same.

I don't have much idea about C# but your code would be something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;

namespace MyFirstAutoScript
{
 class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
       driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://yelitzascareerjourney.wordpress.com/");
       new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("About Me"))).Click().Build().Perform();
       driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("My Resume")).Click(); //my page brakes here
       more commands go here...
       }
    }
}
```

> I had used `new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("About Me"))).Click().Build().Perform();` to mouse over on menu item.

Comment: @sircapsalot The LinkText comand is looking for a menu-item in the menu of the page. @Sadik Ali how is the wait function? @Deeb it didn't work with `PartialLink`. @Abhishek Yadav Thank you it worked with your suggestion. I also added the reference                                                                                `using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;` for the Actions property. `new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("About Me"))).Click().Build().Perform();`

Comment: @Lisa, Nice to hear this worked for you, I updated imports. Please accept my answer, Thanks.